# How to check if preload is running or not?

Tags: 20.04, startup, system-monitor, autorun, preload

I've installed preload like 4-5 days ago. Still I can't see any performance difference. Is there any way to check if preload is running or not? I checked on system monitor but couldn't find it. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution.

To check whether preload is working or not,  follow these steps:

- first, open system monitor
- click on the 3 dots menu icon
- select all processes

In all processes, you will find preload, check if it is on or not.

If it is on then preload is working and if it is off then preload is not working (you can turn it on).

Answer (score 2):

Preload doesn't always increase performance!

It only improves the performance of most frequently used apps and also increases the ram usage (not too much)

Preload just do a little thing. It already stores the app's small amount of processing data in the RAM or HDD (depending on how you've configured it. Next time when you open the app it will open faster than before as it has to fetch less data for processing.

To see if preload is running or not you can see all the services and find if preload is running or not.

To list all services, you can run-

```
service --status-all
```

If preload looks like:

```
[ + ]  preload
```

Then it is working.

Else it is not working

To start it you can run

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install preload && sudo service preload start && sudo systemctl enable preload.service
```

You can visit [man page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/preload.8.html) of preload to know more about it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following command:

```
sudo service preload status
```